# Why do smoothed line plots change when I combine them using ggplot?

Tags: r

I have these 3 datasets for three different disease groups with a health score. When I combine them in one dataset and plot them, they appear differently compared to their individual plots (as shown below).

After adding a variable called "disease" in each of them "healthy, HF, stroke", I combined the three datasets this way

```
d1<- rbind(healthy_clean,HF_clean, Stroke_clean)
```

then I checked the number of individuals in the new dataset (d1) compared to the original and they were the same. Also, I checked the mean, SD, max and min of the health score for each disease group in d1 and they were exactly as in the original.

any idea why it is not the same lines on the overall line plot?

this is my code for the separate plots and the combined one

```
#####example of separate:
ggplot(data=healthy_clean, aes(x=age, y=Mental.Health_T.score,fill=Gender, linetype=Gender)) + 
  geom_smooth(alpha=0) + 
  scale_x_log10() + 
  scale_y_log10() + 
  xlab("Age (Years)") + 
  ylab("Health Global Score")+
  ggtitle("healthy individuals")+
  xlim(19,97)



#####code for the combined plot
ggplot(data=d1, aes(x=age, y=Mental.Health_T.score, color=disease , linetype=Gender)) + 
  geom_smooth(alpha=0) + 
  scale_x_log10() + 
  scale_y_log10() + 
  xlab("Age (Years)") + 
  ylab("Health Global Score")+
  xlim(19,97)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c('solid','dashed'))+
  guides(lty = guide_legend(override.aes = list(col = 'black')))+
  theme(legend.position = "top", legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

here you can see my three independent dataset

```
    healthy <-
      structure(
        list(
          PIN = 3:32,
          age = c(
            38L,
            40L,
            38L,
            39L,
            51L,
            44L,
            59L,
            46L,
            39L,
            39L,
            42L,
            53L,
            37L,
            46L,
            36L,
            51L,
            36L,
            61L,
            39L,
            48L,
            47L,
            43L,
            51L,
            41L,
            39L,
            53L,
            41L,
            52L,
            46L,
            44L
          ),
          Gender = c(
            "M",
            "F",
            "M",
            "F",
            "M",
            "M",
            "F",
            "M",
            "F",
            "M",
            "M",
            "M",
            "F",
            "F",
            "F",
            "M",
            "F",
            "M",
            "F",
            "M",
            "M",
            "F",
            "F",
            "F",
            "F",
            "F",
            "M",
            "M",
            "M",
            "M"
          ),
          Mental.Health_T.score = c(
            46.6,
            32.9,
            28.2,
            46.8,
            58.7,
            58,
            49.3,
            54,
            43.3,
            37.4,
            51.6,
            53.1,
            21.3,
            61.8,
            48,
            33.8,
            46.6,
            51.6,
            62.4,
            54.6,
            50.9,
            54,
            51.6,
            49.8,
            67.6,
            66.5,
            62.4,
            67.6,
            58.3,
            56.8
          ),
          Physical.Health_T.score = c(
            42.6,
            37.2,
            42,
            34.7,
            55.4,
            59.3,
            55.2,
            42.1,
            31.1,
            31.9,
            45.6,
            54.4,
            42.6,
            59.3,
            39.5,
            19.7,
            45.2,
            44,
            54.5,
            46.5,
            48.6,
            52,
            41.6,
            36.2,
            67.7,
            57.8,
            57.8,
            54.7,
            54.4,
            48.9
          ),
          disease = c(
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy",
            "Apparently healthy"
          )
        ),
        row.names = c(NA,
                      30L),
        class = "data.frame"
      )


heart failure_dataset <-
  structure(
    list(
      PIN = c(
        4201L,
        4331L,
        4357L,
        4358L,
        4360L,
        4362L,
        4366L,
        4367L,
        4368L,
        4370L,
        4374L,
        4377L,
        4378L,
        4383L,
        4384L,
        4386L,
        4387L,
        4388L,
        4390L,
        4391L,
        4393L,
        4394L,
        4399L,
        4401L,
        4408L,
        4410L,
        4412L,
        4414L,
        4415L,
        4416L
      ),
      age = c(
        59L,
        38L,
        29L,
        21L,
        28L,
        34L,
        35L,
        26L,
        34L,
        39L,
        26L,
        34L,
        28L,
        42L,
        19L,
        49L,
        75L,
        53L,
        55L,
        22L,
        27L,
        35L,
        35L,
        40L,
        45L,
        44L,
        32L,
        27L,
        30L,
        48L
      ),
      Gender = c(
        "M",
        "M",
        "M",
        "F",
        "F",
        "F",
        "F",
        "M",
        "M",
        "F",
        "F",
        "M",
        "M",
        "M",
        "F",
        "F",
        "M",
        "M",
        "F",
        "M",
        "F",
        "M",
        "F",
        "M",
        "F",
        "M",
        "M",
        "F",
        "F",
        "F"
      ),
      Mental.Health_T.score = c(
        44.8,
        51.8,
        67.6,
        37.5,
        56.7,
        52.2,
        30.7,
        56.7,
        51.6,
        48,
        44.2,
        54.6,
        62.4,
        67.6,
        45.3,
        48,
        58.7,
        56,
        63.6,
        27.9,
        43.5,
        53.2,
        55.3,
        67.6,
        58.9,
        51.6,
        49.3,
        63.6,
        58.7,
        37.5
      ),
      Physical.Health_T.score = c(
        46.3,
        26.5,
        61.6,
        51.5,
        46.3,
        44.3,
        28.5,
        54.7,
        44.3,
        40.5,
        62.2,
        48.6,
        54.6,
        59.3,
        45.6,
        54.4,
        48.2,
        39.5,
        44.3,
        47.8,
        37.5,
        53.5,
        42.4,
        47.8,
        42.1,
        49.2,
        51.5,
        62.2,
        46.9,
        32.2
      ),
      disease = c(
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure",
        "Heart failure"
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, 30L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )





stroke_dataset <-
  structure(
    list(
      PIN = c(
        4155L,
        4156L,
        4157L,
        4158L,
        4159L,
        4160L,
        4161L,
        4162L,
        4164L,
        4165L,
        4166L,
        4167L,
        4168L,
        4169L,
        4170L,
        4171L,
        4172L,
        4173L,
        4174L,
        4175L,
        4176L,
        4177L,
        4178L,
        4179L,
        4180L,
        4181L,
        4182L,
        4183L,
        4184L,
        4185L
      ),
      age = c(
        54L,
        42L,
        66L,
        45L,
        28L,
        55L,
        70L,
        36L,
        60L,
        65L,
        40L,
        57L,
        41L,
        41L,
        37L,
        39L,
        19L,
        42L,
        58L,
        33L,
        63L,
        41L,
        45L,
        42L,
        42L,
        39L,
        55L,
        41L,
        52L,
        63L
      ),
      Gender = c(
        "M",
        "M",
        "F",
        "M",
        "M",
        "M",
        "M",
        "M",
        "M",
        "M",
        "M",
        "M",
        "F",
        "M",
        "F",
        "M",
        "M",
        "F",
        "M",
        "M",
        "M",
        "M",
        "F",
        "M",
        "M",
        "F",
        "M",
        "M",
        "M",
        "M"
      ),
      Mental.Health_T.score = c(
        29.6,
        67.6,
        32.8,
        40.8,
        50.5,
        43.3,
        40.7,
        34.7,
        46.6,
        36.7,
        51.6,
        44.3,
        25,
        45.3,
        35.1,
        45.6,
        45.5,
        51.6,
        45.3,
        62.4,
        46.6,
        48.1,
        40.7,
        42,
        56.8,
        47.9,
        62.4,
        57.6,
        51.6,
        40.7
      ),
      Physical.Health_T.score = c(
        32.9,
        67.7,
        26.5,
        38.4,
        43.4,
        39,
        49,
        31.9,
        37.6,
        34.2,
        41.6,
        36.9,
        24.5,
        50.4,
        31.9,
        53.8,
        44.7,
        37.3,
        41.6,
        57.9,
        39.9,
        29,
        31.8,
        34.2,
        54.4,
        40.5,
        47.2,
        58.7,
        50.7,
        41.6
      ),
      disease = c(
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke"
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, 30L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )
```

Comment: Hi @Ram6, Can you please provide us with a reproducible sample or the first three rows of each your three independent datasets? That would help us help you better. But taking a guess here, perhaps the y-axis needs to be fixed; the smooth lines may appear to be different in the 3-disease-group integrated plot because the y-scales in the three independent plots are not the same.

Comment: Perhaps if you add `ylim(20,75)` to all independent plots and the integrated plot, the smooth lines may look the same across all plots.

Comment: Hi  LC-datascientist,
I added a reducible sample of the 3 datasets. please, have a look. thanks!

I tried adding this (ylim(20,75) but didn't work

Comment: when I use this dataset the graphs in the combined vs separate plots are identical.  please check that this subset of the data reproduces your problem

Comment: I just checked and it provides the same problem!
not sure why we don't see same results.

I combined the three datasets bu this code:       
"d1<- rbind(healthy_dataset,HF_dataset, stroke_dataset)"

would you like to share your figures please?

Comment: ive posted them as an answer

Comment: thanks, George. 
I think the problem is in my overall dataset. I checked everything and nothing wrong with it!
Could you please repeat the steps using whole dataset which is uploaded on my Google Drive?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tovwKTW5Fg5-j44LEcYoh89DyrL5W67c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: see my edited answer for the solution

Comment: no words to describe my gratitude.
thanks, George. You solved it all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `geom_smooth` is using different smoothing methods for the combined vs individual datasets.  You can see this in the messages that appear when you run the plots.

From the documentation:

> method:  smoothing method (function) to use, eg. lm, glm, gam, loess, rlm. For
> datasets with n < 1000 default is loess. For datasets with 1000 or
> more observations defaults to gam

If I don't select the methods then the individual plots of the smaller plots use `loess` smoothing while the 'healthy' and combined plot use `gam`.

[image]

and you see the messages:

```
`geom_smooth()` using method = 'gam' and formula 'y ~ s(x, bs = "cs")'
`geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
`geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
`geom_smooth()` using method = 'gam' and formula 'y ~ s(x, bs = "cs")'
```

If I force each `geom_smooth` to use `loess` (with `method="loess"`) then the plots are the same:

[image]

```
`geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
`geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
`geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
`geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

Be careful though, I got a couple of warnings about data points being removed, and I'm not sure if the parameters of the loess smoothing are the same for each so you should still check that.